# What can I do with R cannot be resolved problem?

Tags: android, eclipse

If I make a new Android project in Ecplipse and I try, to open one of the samples from android SDK, I have got an error, look like this:

> R cannot be resolved

What can I do, to be able, to run these files? I tried to delete import android.R; but nothing changed.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you might try is "clean" your project (option in the menu). If it persists:

There should be an error that stops R from being generated. Check the "problems" tab (?) in eclipse to see what that problem is, and solve that. It could be missing libs, or various other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You possibly got error in building resources.
Possible fixes:

-refresh your project (F5)

-clean you project and refresh

-see "Console" tab, sometimes the problem is shown there

-reload the Android SDK

-restart the Eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML-Layout files. The problem come here half a time.

If you are sure it is note your layout file, check in your java build path if the google librarys are well set. (Google APIs)

(sorry for my bad english)